# Cannot run tutorial procedure in SQL Developer: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm learning PL/SQL on an Oracle 19c virtual machine server downloaded from official website. Client is SQL Developer for Linux and macOS.

**Problem 1**: On attempt to run the following code exactly the same from Lynda.com tutorial where the instructor ran without a problem, I get the prompt "

```
Procedure PROC1 compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
14/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET" 
Errors: check compiler log"
```

the code that doesn't run on my side:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE proc1 (
    emp_id IN NUMBER
) IS
    emp_fname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        first_name
    INTO emp_fname
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employee_id = emp_id;

    dbms_output.put_line('Employee name is: ' || emp_fname);
END;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

EXEC proc1(100)
```

**Problem 2**: whatever I put in the worksheet, the Run menu has every item down greyed out on both macOS and Linux as shown in the screenshot:
[I'm not allowed to embed pictures in my post yet. Please click to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32PdB.png)

For this reason, I can't find a way to step into the code that doesn't run on my side. Can anyone tell me why please?

Comment: You need a slash (`/`) on a line on its own after the `END;`, to terminate and run the PL/SQL block. Once the procedure has compiled you can open it in the object viewer, from the panel on the left, and will be able to run it from that view (rather than from the worksheet).

Comment: Link to the tutorial?

Comment: the `/` after `END;` doesn't affect anything. The tutorial didn't mention that, and I also tried tweaking it with no luck.   Link to the tutorial: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/oracle-database-12c-advanced-sql/creating-pl-sql-procedures-and-functions?autoAdvance=true&autoSkip=false&autoplay=true&resume=false&u=2167290

Comment: The tutorial seems to be behind a paywall. Does it specifically say to run it in SQL Developer, all at once, in one worksheet?

Comment: The instructor pasted all the code directly into the worksheet window of SQL Developer and ran the exec clause without a problem.

Comment: If you want to run all of that code at once as a script then you need a slash on a line on its own after the `END;`. That's just how it works. With all the code selected as it is in your image, you can run it as a statement (command-enter, or the green 'play' icon) or as a script (F5, or the the document-plus-play icon). If the code isn't selected then you can run it all as a script. But either way, you need the slash. If you select *just* the procedure code you can run that as a statement without the slash; and then run the set/exec afterwards.